# PyCharm won't install PyTorch - Building wheel failed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, pytorch

I have tried for some time to install PyTorch and TorchVision to aid in some neural networks / ML projects I'm doing.

My issue is that I can' seem to get the installation to work, neither in PyCharm pip, Anaconda prompt or the cmd/with the pip3 command.

The output I get when trying to run the following command through PyCharm:

```
pip install --user pytorch==0.1.2
```

is this:

```
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/41/4487bc23e3ac4d674943176f5aa309427b011e00607eb98899e9d951f67b/pytorch-0.1.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pytorch: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pytorch: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Even\Anaconda3\envs\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Even\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pytorch\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2sfgqmm7 --python-tag cp36:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
      raise Exception(message)
  Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch: started
    Running setup.py install for pytorch: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Even\Anaconda3\envs\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Even\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pytorch\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1jx5e1ke\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for pytorch
Command "C:\Users\Even\Anaconda3\envs\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Even\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pytorch\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1jx5e1ke\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Even\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\
```

I've also tried this command (CMD):

```
pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m- 
win_amd64.whl
```

Which returned in this output:

```
torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
platform.
```

I might be missing some crucial information, but I've been googling, searching forums, and asked people I know about this. No one has an answer. I hope some of you may have encountered the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 -V` / `python3 -V` / `python3 -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_platform())"`?

Comment: `pip3 -V` gives `pip 18.0 from C:\Users\Even\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)`.

Comment: `python -V` gives `Python 3.6.5` (python3 doesn't seem to work. I'm on Windows, if that is related)

Comment: The last one gives `win32`. @hoefling

Comment: PyTorch doesn't work on 32-bit system. Please use Windows and Python 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, verify if the installation is complete in the local terminal. Look out for windows specific installation from https://pytorch.org/

Once this is done, make sure that you select the correct python interpreter in pycharm. Refer the link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html to  manage packages for a particular Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

1. I solved this on https://pytorch.org/ as told by error. And suffered from

   torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
   platform

. as well. But I figured out it is my CUDA version that cause the error. I thought it was 8/9, but it's 10 actually. You can check pip and python version with `pip --version`.

2. There is another point that we should notice. Pip and Anaconda install packages in different ways. Previously, Pytorch was installed by Anaconda, but I cannot import in Anaconda Prompt (`No module named torch`). I have to use pip to install to fix the error.

Hope this would help.